# OPSHUB OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. There is no working folder mapping for $/

Tags: opshub

I'm trying to migrate from a TFS 2010 to VSO. Got 6 out 7 projects migrated. the last one, and the biggest of all, gives me this error message during the version control migration -> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. There is no working folder mapping for $/. The folder in question has been created in VSO and all the users have been mapped. When looking at the log file, I do get a java exception messages "There is no working folder mapping for $/". I'm running V1.3.1.000. Please help?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, Can you check the length of the path for which it is giving error. Is it greater than 256 characters?

Comment: Hi, The given folder is about 24 characters long. When I consult the OpsHub.log file, the last branch is about 114 characters long.

Comment: No, not just the folder. The path of the whole item that is being shown in the error.

Comment: Here's the path I'm having -> $/CIMSilverlight/CIM 4.2. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Hi Fred, we are looking into the issue. Let us get back to you.

Comment: Let me know if you need any information. Thank you

Comment: Hi Fred, is it possible to shed some more light on the folder in question. What is the changetype associated with it in that changeset? In case of rename/move/branch, can you share what the older path was?

Comment: Hello, Is there a way for me to share the log file with you? Tx

Comment: Yes, you can connect with us through ovsmu@opshub.com. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Fred, the issue has been fixed in the latest version of OVSMU. Please try it out :)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying it out and I'll let you know. Thank you very much guys.